How to get "resource-id" from element in Android app
I am new to Android development and am trying to use Appium to replay events recorded in a Kotlin Android app. I am first going to send the events to some endpoint, then read this data and perform the replay, so for this I need some notion of a "selector" to find the elements by when using Appium. When I do String pageSource = driver.getPageSource(); and output this to a text file, I see that there is a field "resource-id" with format: resource-id="com.vishalgaur.shoppingapp:id/login_login_btn". In the app's code I have a reference to this element: binding.loginLoginBtn. How do I get this resource-id field from the loginLoginBtn element from within the app? Is there way I can access it from binding.loginLoginBtn.*?
